# Understanding the wtforms StringField implementation

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am playing around with wtforms in Flask and am specifically interested in understanding some aspects of the the implementation of the StringField class.

So I have the following user defined class:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class LoginForm(Form):

    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Now I instantiate the class like this:

```
from flask import request
form = LoginForm(request.form)
```

Now when I do this:

> form.username.data

I am basically referring to the *data* member of the *username* object (which is an object of the *StringField* class). Right ?

**Now I wanted to understand where is this *data* coming from ?**

So I went ahead to the implementation of the *StringFiled* class, which I found in the following location :

> site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py

*core.py being a pretty big file can not be pasted here*

Now in core.py the implementation of the **StringField class** was :

```
class StringField(Field):
    """
    This field is the base for most of the more complicated fields, and
    represents an ``<input type="text">``.
    """
    widget = widgets.TextInput()

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            self.data = valuelist[0]
        else:
            self.data = ''

    def _value(self):
        return text_type(self.data) if self.data is not None else ''
```

Now in this class the first place where the **data** member appears (in fact is set) is in the line

```
self.data = valuelist[0]
```

inside the process_formdata() where it gets attached to the calling object (in our case the object *username*) and then it finally gets returned in the _value().

However the process_formdata() itself never gets called anywhere in the entire core.py file except for 1 place, viz., inside the Field class method (which StringField inherits) *process()*

But the point is, the *process()* method also itself does not really get called anywhere in the entire core.py.

**So the question is**:

How exactly is the *self.data* set when the line of code doing that is never reached at all ? I am sure am missing something. Please help me understand this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Cool. Got this by learning how to debug a Flask app using pycharm and then stepping into/over some code. One trick part in the debugging was to configure the debug settings to pass in the parameters required to run the app. In my case the app was being run by using the Manager module from the flask_script as:

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from project import app, db

app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

and while running it this way runserver needs to be given as an argument, like :

> python manage.py runserver

so this *runserver* argument needed to be given during the debug as well. 
So to do this (after you have put a break point in the line *form = LoginForm(request.form)* where actually everything starts):

1. goto the main run file file, i.e. manage.py, that holds the above
   code.
2. Goto *Run* in the main menu -> *Debug*
3. From the window that pops up, choose *Edit Configurations* option
4. In the RHS pane, in the *Script Parameters* give the value as *runserver*
5. Apply and then click debug.

Now when you submit the form in the browser, you would hit the break point put above. Now you can simply step into/over the code (as required) and follow the flow of execution to trace when the method actually gets called.

So the process() here basically gets called from the following path:

> site-packages/wtforms/forms.py

and the code snippet that calls it is :

```
    for name, field, in iteritems(self._fields):
        if obj is not None and hasattr(obj, name):
            field.process(formdata, getattr(obj, name))
        elif name in kwargs:
            field.process(formdata, kwargs[name])
        else:
            field.process(formdata)
```

and the above file comes into the picture because of this line in the user defined file, forms.py

> from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField